# In XCUITest, Syntax to find order of the table view cells and section headers getting displayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

While querying for elements in XCUITest, it usually returns the elements in the order it is displayed.

For example: `XCUIApplication().tables.cells.allElementBoundByIndex`, will return an array of `[XCUIElement]` in the order it's been displayed in the UI.

Unable to fetch section headers and cells together in the displayed order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the list of cells displayed between each sections, I had to use frame.

XCUIElement().frame.origin.y

I was trying to confirm the order of section header and elements displayed with the header. Unable to find a syntax in XCUITest to fetch both section header and table view cells **together in displayed order**. This is because the table view cells are identified using XCUIApplication().tables.cells, and section headers are identified using XCUIApplication().tables.otherElements.

Step: 1,

I added separate accessibility identifier to Section header cell and cell displayed between headers.

Step: 2,

Get the normal table cells list and the other elements cells list separately.

```
let elementIDMatchingPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == %@","kPodcastCellID")
let podcastCellsList: [XCUIElement] = XCUIApplication().tables.cells.matching(elementIDMatchingPredicate).allElementsBoundByIndex



 let elementIDMatchingPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == %@","kPodcastSectionHeaderCellID")
let podcastCellsHeaderList: [XCUIElement] = XCUIApplication().tables.otherElements.matching(elementIDMatchingPredicate).allElementsBoundByIndex
```

Note: Sometimes otherElements within tables might get repeated, It is better to add identifier to element getting displayed within cell and fetch it.

Step: 3,

Loop through the list and append  it to the Two-Dimensional array, So that you can add section header or footer in first and last column of each row. Adding elements to one dimensional might make it difficult to identify the elements between two section headers.

```
for hIndex in 0...(podcastCellsHeaderList.count - 1) {
        //get the ycoordinates of header at hIndex and (hIndex+1)
    //If its last header, y coordinates should be last of element.frame.origin.y + 1(not podcast header)
    for cIndex in 0...(podcastCellsList.count - 1) {

    //get the cells which has yCoordinates >= hIndex and lesser than hIndex+1
    }
}
```